# How do I select all in the WHERE condition?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a set of SQL statement which I will need to make use of the where condition but I would like to know how to select all with the where condition in place. Thus what will be required to be inserted in the parameters to make it select all?

```
@param1 nvarchar(max),
@param2 nvarchar(max)

DECLARE @SQLnvarchar(max)


SET @SQL= 'SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE Column1 IN (@param1) AND Column2 IN (@param2)'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

I tried putting the column name in to the param e.g column1 into @param1 but it does not return me all the data. For example table1 consist of 4524 rows but using the above it only returns me 309 rows. How can I solve this?

Comment: Can't you just add an `OR true`?

Comment: what is it  suppose to mean? The reason being is actually Im passing in parameters thus sometimes it can be based on condition and sometimes it can be select all.  I need the in clause actually

Comment: then `OR parameter is null`

Comment: Check out @Mureinik 's answer..

Comment: Please create a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with the problem so that we can experiment, since the proposed solutions "is not working", I suspect there are some hidden details here that you aren't telling us.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the entire table, just omit the `where` clause. If you absolutely **must** have it, you could add a dummy `1=1` condition:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE 1 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can guess something from this code

```
@param1 nvarchar(max),
@param2 nvarchar(max)

DECLARE @SQLnvarchar(max)


SET @SQL= 'SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE (Column1 IN (@param1) or 1=1 )AND Column2 IN ((@param2) or 1=1)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to your problem. In your case you can take advantage of COALESCE.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ids NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @classes NVARCHAR(MAX)

--SET @ids = '1,2,3'

SET @sql = N'SELECT id,name,class FROM dbo.Student
WHERE 1 = 1 '
+ COALESCE(' AND id IN (' + @ids + ')', '')
+ COALESCE(' AND class IN (' + @classes + ')', '')

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

And here is the working fiddle for you.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bbbcf/5)

Comment: Can you please create a sql fiddle for your problem so i can look into it.

Comment: When you say "not working for me", what did happen? In order for us to help you, you need to help us help you, you need to give us the details we need in order to help you, like, what did happen when you tried it?

Comment: Hi sry actually I understand my problem that why it does not include all the rows if I were to put WHERE column1 in (column1). the reason is because it does not take in the NULL values thus lesser rows returned. How can I include the NULL values as well then? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The correct way if you *must* execute one specific SQL in all instances and cannot dynamically change it, then you must invent a magic value that means "don't care about this parameter", a typical value would be `NULL`.

To rewrite the SQL to support this you would have:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE (@param1 IS NULL OR Column1 = @param1)
  AND (@param2 IS NULL OR Column2 = @param2)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, then I can't help you. "It's not working" does not tell me anything about your problem that would allow me to help you. You need to be way more explicit about the problem then. *Why* is that not solving your problem? What happens if you try it? *Did* you try it?